# How to display index number and text value in the listbox asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I want to display index value along with the text value of the listbox. If we are moving the item up and down the index value remains the same. only the text hast to change.

Code i am using to move the item up and down:

```
         <script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">
       function MoveUp() {
           var con = document.getElementById("lbRank");
           if (con.selectedIndex >= 0) {
               for (var count = 1; count < con.options.length; count++) {
                   if (con.options[count].selected == true) {
                       var tem = con.options[count].text;
                       con.options[count].text = con.options[count - 1].text;
                       if (con.options[count - 1].selected == false) {
                           con.options[count].selected = false;
                       }
                       con.options[count - 1].selected = true;
                       con.options[count - 1].text = tem;
                   }
               }
           }
           else {
               alert('Select any item');
           }

       }

       function MoveDown() {
           var con = document.getElementById("lbRank");
           if (con.selectedIndex >= 0) {
               for (var count = con.options.length - 2; count >= 0; count--) {
                   if (con.options[count].selected == true) {
                       var tem = con.options[count].text;
                       con.options[count].text = con.options[count + 1].text;
                       if (con.options[count + 1].selected == false) {
                           con.options[count].selected = false;
                       }
                       con.options[count + 1].selected = true;
                       con.options[count + 1].text = tem;
                   }
               }
           }
           else {
               alert('Select any item');
           }
       }
</script>
```

Comment: not sure what is the question here! What do you mean by index? Option element has index (within list), value and text. Do you want to move up/down option's text while keeping option's value intact?

Comment: i want to display, index of each item in the listbox. if we are moving the item up/down the index value remains the same, only the text value hast to change

Comment: you need to include index value in the text. You can have use say space to separate index & actual text. So when you move the items up & down, extract the text part and use it accordingly.